# SQL get row value where count of rows for that row value matches with of the column of that row-value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table in oracle db as follow.

```
ID  | TOTAL_IDS
----+----------
A1  + 2
A1  + 2
B1  + 1
C1  + 3
C1  + 3
C1  + 3
D1  + 2
```

I want list of IDs where count of distinct IDs matches with TOTAL_IDs. For eg. count of ID A1 is 2 and it matches TOTAL_IDS column.

So my query should return A1,B1,C1.

Comment: What if you add (D1,1)?

Comment: You've hopefully created this table only for practising purposes. In a real database such table should not exists of course.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - The table does exist in oracle db. But this is just to represent original db.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try Having clause : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/06eed6/9

`min=max`   ==> all row have the same value (group by IDS)

`min=count` ==> your expected citeria

```
select
    IDS
from
    your_table
group by
    IDS
having
    min(TOTAL_IDS) = count(*) and
    max(TOTAL_IDS) = min(TOTAL_IDS)
```

return :

```
| IDS |
|-----|
|  A1 |
|  B1 |
|  C1 |
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct id
from tablename t1
where TOTAL_IDS = (select count(*) from tablename t2
                   where t2.id = t1.id)
```

Will not detect inconsistent table data, e.g. if ('D1', 4) or ('D2',null) is added to the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID,count(ID) from table group by ID having count(ID)=count(TOTAL_IDS);
```

Comment: it is recommended that you should write some description regarding your answer

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
SELECT ID, TOTAL_IDS
FROM tb
GROUP BY ID, TOTAL_IDS
HAVING COUNT(ID) = TOTAL_IDS
```